# Can speculative execution of modern CPUs cross loop iterations?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, pipeline, cpu-architecture, speculative-execution

Consider below loop (https://godbolt.org/z/z4Wz1aanK) that has no loop-carried dependence. Will modern CPU speculatively execute next iteration with previous one?  if true, is loop expansion still necessary here?

```c
void bar(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
    out[i] = foo(src[i]);
}
```

The result of compilation:

```
bar():
       pushq   %rbx
       xorl    %ebx, %ebx
.L2:
       movl    src(%rbx), %edi
       addq    $4, %rbx
       call    foo(int)
       movl    %eax, out-4(%rbx)
       cmpq    $4096, %rbx
       jne     .L2
       popq    %rbx
       ret
src:
       .zero   400
out:
       .zero   400
```

**Update1**: Now I am sure speculative execution can cross loop iterations. The question is how far that can be, considering dependency chain introduced by loop count `i`?

Comment: make two codeblocks, one for C, one for assembly, to get syntax highlighting

Comment: How far?  Even without unrolling, it's going to be limited by the size of the loop body moreso than the 1-cycle loop-carried dependency, especially with a non-inline function call in the loop. (But yes, call/ret can be correctly predicted and speculated past). https://blog.stuffedcow.net/2013/05/measuring-rob-capacity/ - modern CPUs (like Zen 4 and Alder Lake) have ROB capacities of several hundred uops, scheduler sizes over 100 (with per-port scheduling and non-scheduling queues on AMD).  https://chipsandcheese.com/2022/11/05/amds-zen-4-part-1-frontend-and-execution-engine/

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this loop will likely benefit from branch prediction / speculative execution.

Loop unrolling by hand is generally considered to be an obsolete optimization, see for example here: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/avoid-manual-loop-unrolling.html

Speculative execution does not change the observed behaviour of your program. It does not even require compiler-support since it is something the CPU itself does when it encounters conditional jumps. Whether your iterations will be correctly predicted will depend on what happens inside of `foo` and possibly even the data in `src`. If `foo` has too many conditionals or if the conditionals follow hard-to-predict patterns, the speed will be lower.

Other optimizations may appear in the code though if the compiler thinks they are beneficial: There might be loop unrolling, there might be SIMD-operations. To see what the compiler actually does with your code you can try **https://godbolt.org/**

Comment: Thank you. Will the loop count construct a dependence chain since the inc depends on previous value?

Comment: Not fully sure what you mean by "construct a dependence chain". If you are worried that your `i++`-style-loop will force the machine to execute the iterations one after another, I recommend you play around with godbolt a bit. You will see that modern compilers with optimizations turned on can do a lot of things with your loops. 'Trivial' loops like yours are abstract control structures to the optimizer. There will be no `i` variable on the stack, it will exist in a register, or maybe the compiler wants to increment the pointer value directly and `i` will not exist in any way.

Comment: yes, I mean the `i++`, `src[i]`,`out[i]`. Gcc will turn `i++` into 'add     rbx, 4'. So I think the parallelism only hapends after the previous rbx is calculated even the `rbx` is overwritten, right? (I pasted the asm code in question.)

Comment: @ChangbinDu You cannot see speculative in the assembly output, it's a cpu-feature, a detail in how the assembly gets executed. It is true your asm does not include parallelism. It cannot contain parallelism because the compiler cannot reason about `foo`.

Comment: Please ignore compiler level parallelism optmization here. All I tried to discuss is about hardware level. (sorry for my unclear description, just think the `foo` can be anything.)

Comment: 1) instruction level parallelism (branch prediction and instruction pipelining) is simply not visible in assembly. There is no instruction to `trigger` it. The cpu just does it if possible. You might want to use valgrind to get statistics about how well branch prediction works for you (but that depends also on data, not just code) 2) The fact that `foo` can be anything is relevant to the compiler - it has to just compile the code into a `call` to that function. If `foo` is known, your loop might be compiled differently.